# JOIN on django orm

Tags: django, join, orm, django-orm

1.
1.1. query: 
QuestionRequestAnswerModel.objects.filter(request_no__exact=index['id']).select_related('answer_user').values('answer_user', 'amount', 'select_yn')
[image]

2.
2.1. query:
QuestionRequestAnswerModel.objects.filter(request_no__exact=index['id']).select_related('answer_user')[0].answer_user

[image]

3. description
   I want to get answer_user's last_name.
   but when I use django orm by select_realated('answer_user'),
   the result give me the answer_user's id only.

how can I get another column, except id, on ORM join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow foreign key relationships in value queries by using the double underscore notation

```
QuestionRequestAnswerModel.objects.filter(
    request_no__exact=index['id']
).select_related(
    'answer_user'
).values(
    'answer_user__last_name',
    'amount',
    'select_yn'
)
```